# How to get the JSON response using same AJAX mechanism

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

here is the Ajax code i use

```
function AJAXInteraction(url, callback) {
    var req = init();
    req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function init() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }

    function processRequest () {
        // readyState of 4 signifies request is complete
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            // status of 200 signifies sucessful HTTP call
            if (req.status == 200) {
                if (callback) callback(req.responseXML);
            }
        }
    }

    this.doGet = function() {
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
        }
    }

function mainCall(){
    var req_url = "requestItems.php?format=json&num=100"
    var ajax = new AJAXInteraction(req_url, firstPageData);
    ajax.doGet();   
}

function firstPageData(resJSON){
}
```

At the beginning of the page load, i call `mainCall()`. When i call the same system with XML format this functions works perfectly. But when i call with JSON format, then `firstPageData(resJSON)`, `resJSON` becomes null.

any ideas?

Comment: You are doing this: `if (callback) callback(req.responseXML);` which looks like it is expecting XML.  Somewhere in your ajax function, you you have to treat the response as JSON (presumably parsing it).

Comment: Have you verified that the correct data is arriving?

Comment: yes. I checked with firbug, it returns the JSON and in JSON format.

Comment: You need to look at `req.responseText` rather than `req.responseXML`. It will be stringified JSON. You will need to turn that string into a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function processRequest () {
        // readyState of 4 signifies request is complete
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            // status of 200 signifies sucessful HTTP call
            if (req.status == 200) {
                var type = req.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                if (type.indexOf("xml") !== -1 && req.responseXML)
                    callback(req.responseXML);
                else if (type=== "application/json")
                    callback(JSON.parse(req.responseText));
                else
                    callback(req.responseText);
                //if (callback) callback(req.responseXML);
            }
        }
```

This worked !!, I found it in *[JavaScript: The Definitive Guide: The Definitive Guide](http://books.google.fi/books?id=6TAODdEIxrgC&pg=PA501&lpg=PA501&dq=callback%28req.responseXML%29%20json&source=bl&ots=obbmMTMsZF&sig=ZKn5L6Li_O5LOXO4oV8KbQNn0J4&hl=fi&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=callback%28req.responseXML%29%20json&f=false)*

Comment: You might want to also put a `try`/`catch` block around the `JSON.parse` in case the JSON comes back malformed.